# Update an Object/Instance by overwriting the save method of another Model, by using the FK

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have the following models:

```
 class Acc(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField( max_length=35)

class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

    acc = models.ForeignKey(Acc, blank=True, null=True, related_name='owner', on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Note(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField( max_length=35
    receiver = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Item(models.Model):
    note = models.ForeignKey(Notification, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    acc = models.ForeignKey(Acc, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

        .....
        # update note
        Note.objects.filter(id=self.note_id).update(receiver=self.account.owner)
```

I overwrite the `save` method on the `Item` Object/Model, to update the `Note` Model `receiver` using the ForeignKey.

I get the following error:

```
int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'RelatedManager'
```

it is triggered by this line:

```
Note.objects.filter(id=self.note_id).update(receiver=self.acc.owner)
```

The `owner` is the related manager of the `Acc` Model and is a `User`Model, which I want to get for `receiver` key in Note.

Comment: Please show the full traceback.

Comment: added more info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your models seem wrong. User has a ForeignKey to Acc, which means that there are potentially *many* User objects for each Acc. So `acc.owner` is a manager which gives you access to all of those, via for example `acc.owner.all()`.

Either you want the FK to go in the other direction, from Acc to User - which would mean that each User could have many Accs - or you should use a OneToOneField, so that there is one Acc and one User.

Comment: I change the relation to OneToOneField